# Detect add photos only permission

Tags: ios, ios11, phphotolibrary

In ios 11 we now have "Add photos only" permission setting.
[image: ios 11 photos settings]

But how we now determinate which photo library access level is set?
`[PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus]` works only for "Read and Write" permission check. If app asked only for "Add photos only" permission then it stays `PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. If user changed it from "Read and Write" to "Add photos only" it gives `PHAuthorizationStatusDenied`.

So, how can I tell if my app have permissions to do "Export to Camera Roll" feature, which dosen't require read permissions?

Comment: Same problem here. Any luck in finding something?

Comment: @Daniel Tranca As far as I understand in ios11 there is no way to know that we can write to photo library without actually trying to do so and checking for errors (e.g. use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` callback as mikebld suggested). It is unfortunate, because I always disabled "Export to Camera Roll" button, if device denied permissions to library. Now I must always show it and return some error alert if export attempt was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 12):

since iOS 11, in order to gain **only Write access** you'll need to add the `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` in your *info.plist*. 
The problem here arises if you want to check if the user allows you to do that. It cannot be done through the `[PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus]` method, since that calls out the read/write popup (and you'll need to have `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in your *info.plist* too).

If you want to check if the user gave your app access to write, you'll have to call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` (which I'm guessing you already call if you want to add data to the gallery), and that gives you a callback which tells you if the saving worked or not, but the bigger thing is that it shows the user your `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` text.

Now, in order to make sure you have access on both, you should add both `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` added to your *info.plist* and do your regular check with the PHPhotoLibrary, and if that fails, then you can only check when you want to save the data to the library with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

I'd say you can check only with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` but you need to actually save an image to the user gallery to do that and it's hacky, which is a no no.

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 14 you are able to check if the user gave permission for add photos only:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: .addOnly)
```

Unfortunately that means below iOS 14 you don't know if the user has selected the add photos only or another option. The only other way to check is to actually use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` like mikebld said in his answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307475/swift-ask-for-user-s-permission-to-access-the-photo-library/77770550#77770550