# In Swift 4.1 how do you request write-only permission for the photo library?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-permissions

I have my app requesting permission to add to the photo library but I don't need read access.  I see that there is supposed to be an option for this but I can't find how to ask for this access specifically.

I am doing this:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
    if(status == .authorized){
        // save
    }
})
```

And that works fine, but the request displayed is for full access.

Can I specify that I only need write access?   I have both Privacy keys set up in my info.plist

I am running this on a simulator, ios 11.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, access control for `PhotoKit` is not separated between read and write. If you look at [PHAuthorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phauthorizationstatus), there are only cases where full access is granted. No write only option.

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` is the only privacy message you can configure, so you can let the user know that you are only writing, not reading. App store review will make sure that is true.

Edit: also see [Detect add photos only permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341694/detect-add-photos-only-permission) for iOS 11+

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Comment: With iOS 11 and newer, this can actually be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341694/detect-add-photos-only-permission