# NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription required but already in the plist.info

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

im using a screen capture code with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() and then UIActivityViewController to allow users to select what to do with the screenshot image

its all works but when i click on save image i get console error:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  > The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value  explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I checked the plist.info and it already has NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription listed in there

So why is it not recognising it and still giving this error?

I tried deleting derived data and cleaned build folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check plist again if the key is `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`, not  `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`.

Apple document for adding this key to plist and requesting permission :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/protected_resources/requesting_authorization_to_access_photos

Comment: yes ive checked that. but i was thinking do i actually need to run some code to open a dialog to ask the user to accept this permission?

Comment: Be description it specifically points to plist key-value pair issue. 
Anyway, you need to request authorization. Before performing an operation check the current authorization status. you can try requesting permission if permissions are not as expected.
`PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: readWrite) { (authorizationStatus) in
       switch authorizationStatus {
       case .authorized:`

Comment: similar issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307475/swift-ask-for-user-s-permission-to-access-the-photo-library

Comment: check out apple documentation for same: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/protected_resources/requesting_authorization_to_access_photos

Comment: i had to workaround i found that the app automatically shows a dialog to get user authorization when you call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screengrab,nil,nil, nil);